# iOS: 44k audio file should play at 22k sample rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

In my audio app I need to be able to change the format of an audio file (AIFF), more specifically the sample rate. The audio session is running at 22050 Hz, and the audio file itself is created in libpd/Pure Data also running the same sample rate. The problem is that the file appears to be a 44100 Hz audio file, which means that when played back on the device it plays twice as fast.

Is it possible to change the header of the file or something so that its sample rate becomes 22050 Hz, without resampling the audio?

I have seen other related topics where one suggestion is to play the file at half speed. However, this will not solve my problem, as the file will be further compressed to AAC for uploading to a server, and it need to be able to play back at correct speed on other devices.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm... your question doesn't have anything to do with playback on iOS.  You just want to modify an incorrect header in your file?

Comment: Yes Brad, that is correct. The header indicates a 44k audio file, but the file should be played back at 22k to sound correctly.

Comment: Why is the header incorrect?  Is this a one-time need to fix a broken file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was caused by a bug in a file creating object in Pure Data. No matter what sample rate I set the file to be, it ended up being 44100 Hz. So I simply switched to using wav files, and the files ended up having the correct sample rate of 22050, and now play back at correct speed.

All good now!